# Can magento enterprise version handle 10 Million+ products?

Tags: php, magento

We are looking for setup of ecommerce platform with more than 10 million products. Will magento be able to handle these many products? If yes, which magento version 1 or 2 we should go for? What could be the difficulties may arise and possible solutions to them?

Answer (score 0):

1. No Magento enterprises also not support 10Million product you need
   to use different database MySQL does not support million of product
   you can use any of the version in Magento 1.9.x or 2.x both are good
   but in magento2.x development is time taking  otherwise its security
   feature is very high  you can use MongoDB or  Hadoop or any other
   database or you can do one more thing purchase 2 servers one server
   you can install a database and another server you can use Magento 
   this we can  say load balancing